# How do I add encoded query values to a URL?

Tags: ruby, uri, urlencode, open-uri, ruby-1.9.3

I am looking for a convenient and functional way to add encoded values to a URL query string in Ruby.
Currently, I have:

```
require 'open-uri'

u = URI::HTTP.new("http", nil, "mydomain.example", nil, nil, "/tv", nil, "show=" + URI::encode("Rosie & Jim"), nil) 

p u.to_s # => "http://mydomain.example/tv?show=Rosie%20&%20Jim"
```

This isn't what I'm looking for, because I need to get
`"http://mydomain.example/tv?show=Rosie%20%26%20Jim"`, so that the `show=` value is not truncated.

Does Open::URI have another method that would do this? If not, can it be done with any other standard Ruby, or gem?

Comment: You might want to look at the [Addressable](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/) gem. It's everything Ruby's URI is, and a lot more. Highly recommended for anything beyond simple URL manipulation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with `CGI::escape` instead of `URI::encode` . [doc here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape)

Comment: Thanks. That does the job. I noticed that spaces show as pluses; so when I looked that up, I found the encoding in URL queries is called "www_form"; this led me to find a more convenient way to do it with open-uri, but I accept your answer because it does exactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 12):

`URI.encode_www_form` works well and is more convenient for adding multiple arguments

```
q = URI.encode_www_form("show" => "Rosie & Jim", "series" => "3", "episode" => "4")
u = URI::HTTP.new("http", nil, "mydomain.example", nil, nil, "/tv/ragdoll", nil, q, nil)
```